# jasper server gives access denied after login if i use custom domain name instead of localhost

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, jasperserver

I have implemented SSO for jasper server for my Web APP using the steps mentioned in jasper server Authentication Cookbook.First i login into my custom App and then try to access jasper server using http://localhost:8081/jasperserver , it gets authenticated and i am able to login. But when i try to access the same url using custom domain name e.g.- http://lazydev.com:8081/jasperserver i get logged in but when i try to access any menu items it gives Access Denied pop up.

Answer (score 0):

As the users were from different domain that's why it was giving error.